# Upgrade the longest word in a string to capital letters in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I need to write a function (void) in C which gets "char* str", The string includes delimiters (char* delimiters = "?:,-space"). The function needs to update the string itself so that the longest word will be written in capital letters.

That's my code so far:

```
void
longestInCaptital(char *str)
{
    char *delimiters = "?:,- ";
    char copyOfStr[strlen(str)];

    strcpy(copyOfStr, str);
    char *temp = strtok(copyOfStr, delimiters);
    int maxLetters = 0;
    char *tempIndex;

    while (temp) {
        if (strlen(temp) > maxLetters) {
            maxLetters = strlen(temp);
            tempIndex = temp;
        }
        temp = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
    }
    str = tempIndex;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < maxLetters; i++) {
        str[i] = toupper(str[i]);
    }
}
```

i tried to make it work but couldn't,
thanks for the helpers!

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what you have done so far. We abhour "PlZ gIb Me c0dez" types of questions.

Comment: yes of course, sorry for that! im going to edit the question

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais i would be happy if you can help me a little :)

Comment: You may want to fix the formatting too!

Comment: as you can see im new here, can you tell me what do i need to fix in my format? @SeanFrancisN.Ballais

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close. You just needed to apply the *offset* of the start of the largest string in the *copy* to the address of the *original*.

Also, note that `copyOfStr` needs to be `+1` to account for the EOS char.

Note: I've *not* tested this:

```
void
longestInCaptital(char *str)
{
    char *delimiters = "?:,- ";
    char copyOfStr[strlen(str) + 1];

    strcpy(copyOfStr, str);

    int maxLetters = 0;
    char *tempIndex = NULL;

    char *temp = strtok(copyOfStr, delimiters);
    while (temp) {
        int curlen = strlen(temp);
        if (curlen > maxLetters) {
            maxLetters = curlen;
            tempIndex = temp;
        }
        temp = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
    }

    int i;

    // get starting offset within _original_ string
    str += (tempIndex - copyOfStr);

    for (i = 0; i < maxLetters; i++) {
        str[i] = toupper(str[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably easier to do with strspn/strcspn that strtok, given that you want to update the string in place and don't want to write NULs all over it:

```
void longestInCaptital(char *str) {
    char *delimiters = "?:,- ";
    char *longest = 0;
    size_t longest_len = 0, len;
    while (*str) {
        str += strspn(str, delimiters);  // skip any initial delimiter
        len = strcspn(str, delimiters);  // how long is this word?
        if (len > longest_len) {
            longest = str;
            longest_len = len; }
        str += len };
    while (longest_len-- > 0) {
        *longest = toupper(*longest);
        ++longest; }
}
```

`strspn` gives you the number of characters at the front of the string that are in the set of characters passed.  `strcpsn` gives you the number that are NOT in the set.

Comment: UV for a space efficient solution O(1) rather than [O(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53662045/2410359) .  Aside: this is a formatting style I have rarely seen.

Comment: Its compact form -- IMO not putting the `}` on lines by themselves makes it much more readable, as it doesn't break up the vertical spacing as much, so the indent structure is more apparent.

Comment: Have you successful configured an auto formatter to realize this format?